# Jquery hasClass Code not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when any other slide is active besides the home page slide it hides the menu: ocw2018.orangecoastwebsites.com

I was using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('.about-us, .services, .portfolio, ocw-whole-testimonials, .ocw-blog, .contact-us').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active')) {
        $('#menu-main-menu').hide();
    } else {
        $('#menu-main-menu').show();
    }
});
```

In the console, it works fine, but I'm not sure why it's not working on the live site.

Edit:

Basically I want what this code is able to do but with a hasClass instead of hover

```
$(window).on('hover', function(){
    if(
    $('.about-us').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') ||
    $('.services').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
    $('.portfolio').hasClass('active') || 
    $('.ocw-whole-testimonials').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
    $('.ocw-blog').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
    $('.contact-us').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active')) {
        $('#menu-main-menu').hide();
    } else {
        $('#menu-main-menu').show();
    }
});
```

It is live on the URL I provide above, so you can see when you scroll to the next page, and move your mouse, the menu disappears. It's my workaround until I figure out how to make it hidden when a class is active.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] in your question itself so that your problem is reproducible (and strongly consider using line breaks while coding).

Comment: I don't see any event handling. Except if you are interested in one-time only.

Comment: Please be more specific, what excactly does not work? Also: you are missing a `.` at `ocw-whole-testimonials`. My advise would be to get rid of all the other js error on your live site first, before trying to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to know from your post actually exactly what you want. However see below whatever I guessed so far.

First of all you missed `'.'` on `'ocw-whole-testimonials'` it should `'.ocw-whole-testimonials'`.

After that please breakdown the multiple condition instead single line selector series like following, it will confirm you more accurate output, suppose any selector may have the expected selector so will return `true` but any other one may not so what will be out put `false`? so avoid this confusion it is better to breakdown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function hideMenu(){
        if(
        $('.about-us').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') ||
        $('.services').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
        $('.portfolio').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
        $('.ocw-whole-testimonials').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
        $('.ocw-blog').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active') || 
        $('.contact-us').hasClass('uncode-scroll-active')) {
            $('#menu-main-menu').hide();
        } else {
            $('#menu-main-menu').show();
        }
    }

    hideMenu(); // Call when page load

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        hideMenu(); // Call when page scroll
    })
});
```

Comment: Hi there, I want to hide the menu if I scroll to any of the classes in the code have the class "uncode-scroll-active", I tried your code, but when I still scroll to these pages and they have the "uncode-scroll-active" class, it does not hide the menu.

Comment: Please share your html code too and try to create jsfiddle version if possible.

Comment: Updated my question if this not work then I believe this impacting by other issues.

Comment: Hello @Hanif , thank you so much for your reply. On this template, the scroll function does not work. Do you think there may be an alternative way?

Comment: Although I updated my question but I think really need your code in details.

Comment: Thank you Hanif for replying, I'm not really the best at explaining things. Please take a look at my updated question above, so you can see what I am trying to do without the "hover" function.

Comment: Basically, I want what the hover function does, automatically.

Comment: Then you can try "$('body').on('hover'" instead "$(window).on('hover'".

Comment: It helps, but is there some sort of event handler for hasClass? I think that's why it's not working.

Comment: I don't think so, because if anyone contains ".uncode-scroll-active" class it will work this is dose not matter the sorting or ordering position.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    //write your code here
});
```